# How to make many pages in vs code

Tags: html, css, web, visual-studio-code

So I made 200 line code for a website I'm making and then I made a button to open another page that i will code as well but here is the problem I don't know how to start another page in vs code please help I'm beginner at coding I tried searching in YouTube but nothing helped

Comment: first learn how HTTP works, and thus how a web server works

Answer (score 0):

It can be hard to learn how to start - but we've all been there. You can do it!

For a brief starter, in VSCode, you can try this, and start learning from this point.

In your first HTML file button, ideally you'll have HTML similar to this: `<a href="/file2.html"/>`. In VSCode, just create `file2.html` in the same directory as `file1`, and add some HTML. It should populate.